# While loop (really simple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I am working on the code below, I want `temp` be `1` or `2`, but it keeps running in the while loop.

```
temp = input("1 for yes/2 for no")
while (temp!="1" or temp!="2"):
    print("please input 1 or 2")
    temp = input("1 for yes/2 for no")
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
while temp!="1" or temp!="2":
```

to this:

```
while temp!="1" and temp!="2":
```

Comment: my pleasure to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need `and` instead of `or`.

With `or`, the condition will never be satisfied as `temp` can not be both `"1"` and `"2"`:

```
temp=input("1 for yes/2 for no")
while(temp!="1" and temp!="2"):
    print("please input 1 or 2")
    temp=input("1 for yes/2 for no")
print(temp)
```

Comment: cmon man... i just posted that before you.